# How to perform find operation asynchrounously in Scala Mongodb 3.0 Driver without specifying Await and Thread

Tags: mongodb, scala

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.io._
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json4s.native.Serialization._
import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Updates._
import org.mongodb.scala.Document._
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential
import com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientSettings
import com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions
import com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._  

object Async {

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 

{

var mongoClient: MongoClient = null
val credential: MongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("user", "database", "password".toArray)
val clusterSettings: ClusterSettings = ClusterSettings.builder().hosts(List(new ServerAddress("localhost:27017")).asJava).build()
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().codecRegistry(MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY).clusterSettings(clusterSettings).credentialList(List(credential).asJava).build()

mongoClient = MongoClient(settings)

val db: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("database")

var collection: MongoCollection[Document] = db.getCollection("collectionName")

var output : Document = Document()

var query: Document = Document()
var projection: Document = Document()

output = find(query, projection, collection)
println(output)

}

def find(query: Document, projection: Document, collectionName : MongoCollection[Document]) : Document = {
  var previousDoc : Document = Document()
        var future = collectionName.find(equal("_id", query)).projection(projection).toFuture()
                    collectionName.find(equal("_id", query)).projection(projection).subscribe(
                            (data: Document) => { previousDoc = data },                         
                            (error: Throwable) => println(s"Query failed: ${error.getMessage}"), 
                            () => println("Done")                                        
                            )

        Await.result(future, Duration(100000, MILLISECONDS))
        previousDoc
}
}
```

I have performed find operation in mongodb, and here is the code using scala. but execution of above code is going non blocking so process ends before retrieving the data from mongodb. I want to know, how to control non blocking while performing mongodb operations without using Await and Thread.sleep functions.

Answer (score 0):

Future is a sort of a placeholder object that you can create for a result that does not yet exist. Generally, the result of the Future is computed concurrently and can be later collected.

Scala provides combinators such as flatMap, foreach, and filter used to compose futures in a non-blocking way.

you can do something like this

```
future.flatMap{ 
         response => //do something when the response is available ... 
 }
```

use for compensations

```
for {
     response <- fuurure
} yield{
     //do something when the response is available ... 
}
```

Please see this doc for Futures and Promises
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html